# GOTO statement references a label 'QuitWithRollBack' but the label has not been declared

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, goto

I have an SQL script which contains the below section.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
/****** Object:  JobCategory [[Uncategorized (Local)]]    Script Date: 3/30/2017 1:07:04 PM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'PurgeArchivedData_test24X7_ARCHIVE', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'This job will purge the archived data which are older than N number of days. N can be provided as a parameter and the detault value is 180 days.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'sa', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [Delete Old Data]    Script Date: 3/30/2017 1:07:04 PM ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Delete Old Data', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'EXEC [dbo].[usp_PurgeArchive] @Days = 180;', 
        @database_name=N'test24X7_ARCHIVE', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'Purge Weekly', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=8, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=1, 
        @freq_subday_interval=0, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=1, 
        @active_start_date=20170330, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=0, 
        @active_end_time=235959, 
        @schedule_uid=N'a3f53c17-0e55-44c1-b237-cd2650371225'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:

GO
```

When I execute this script from a WiX custom action, I am getting the below shown error. But this error doesn't happen when I manually execute the script from SQL Management Studio.

```
Calling custom action CDSMCustomActions!CDSMCustomActions.CustomActions.InstallDatabase
Begin InstallDatabase
MX4-ERROR : CDSM InstallDB : A GOTO statement references the label 'QuitWithRollback' but the label has not been declared.
A GOTO statement references the label 'QuitWithRollback' but the label has not been declared.
A GOTO statement references the label 'QuitWithRollback' but the label has not been declared.
A GOTO statement references the label 'QuitWithRollback' but the label has not been declared.
A GOTO statement references the label 'QuitWithRollback' but the label has not been declared.
A GOTO statement references the label 'QuitWithRollback' but the label has not been declared.
```

What am  I doing wrong here? There are no other parts in the script which uses the GOTO statement. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: mssql studio requires sql server agent that's why executing it works but in wix - it's not a sql studio and does not have an sql server agent.. i supposed what you can do is dissect the statements and make it a procedure and call it from wix

Answer (score 0):

Your script is apparently being separated after the first GOTO. So from research you could save your script as an .sql file and call/execute it with WiX. [Reference](http://www.rareese.com/blog/using-wix-to-install-sql-databases-and-execute-sql-scripts)

Another suggestion that should make it work, although not the preferred method, is to remove GOTO or replace GOTO with ROLLBACK TRANSACTION.